# jQuery UI Autocomplete - No results found

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, jquery-ui

I have the following

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" class="auto" name="search" autocomplete="off">
</form>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function($){
    $('.auto').autocomplete({
     source:'connect.php',
     minLength:1
    });
  });
</script>
```

And connect.php
I KNOW I have to sanitize $term before inputting it into my query.

```
if(isset($_GET['term'])) {
  require "db.php";

  $con = mysqli_connect("$host","$user","$password","$db");

  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

  $term = $_GET['term'];
  $query = "SELECT `name` FROM `products` WHERE `name` LIKE '%$term%'";
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo json_encode($row);
  }
}
```

If I typed `M` in the input field and use chrome tools to inspect the response, I get this.

> {"0":"MacBook Pro 13-inch","name":"MacBook Pro 13-inch"}{"0":"MacBook
>   Pro 15-inch","name":"MacBook Pro 15-inch"}{"0":"MacBook Air
>   13-inch","name":"MacBook Air 13-inch"}{"0":"MacBook Air
>   11-inch","name":"MacBook Air 11-inch"}{"0":"iMac
>   21.5-inch","name":"iMac 21.5-inch"}{"0":"iMac 27-inch","name":"iMac 27-inch"}{"0":"Mac Pro Quad-Core","name":"Mac Pro Quad-Core"}{"0":"Mac
>   Pro 6-Core","name":"Mac Pro 6-Core"}

However, for some reason, it states 'No results found' on the page even though there is?

Answer (score 0):

The output your php-script creates is no valid json - you have to wrap the individual objects in an array:

```
[{"0":"MacBook Pro 13-inch","name":"MacBook Pro 13-inch"}, {"0":"MacBook Pro 15-inch","name":"MacBook Pro 15-inch"}, {"0":"MacBook Air 13-inch","name":"MacBook Air 13-inch"}, {"0":"MacBook Air 11-inch","name":"MacBook Air 11-inch"}, {"0":"iMac 21.5-inch","name":"iMac 21.5-inch"}, {"0":"iMac 27-inch","name":"iMac 27-inch"}, {"0":"Mac Pro Quad-Core","name":"Mac Pro Quad-Core"}, {"0":"Mac Pro 6-Core","name":"Mac Pro 6-Core"}]
```

Modify your PHP-script like this:

```
$result = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $result[] = $row;
  }

json_encode($result);
```

In addition to that - your output should have the properties id, value and label, not just "0".

Comment: `$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);`

Your method overwrites that and then the while loop fails. If I change `$result = array();` to `$results` then I get an internal server error 500